# What is wrong with this proof related to modular equations

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Let us consider the following congruence:

$$qx+y+z+t+w≡0(modp)$$

where all the variables are positive integers and $p$ is a prime number. In this case there exist an integer $v$ verifying $$qx+y+z+t+w=vp$$

Solving this equation with respect to $x$ we get $$x=((-(t+w+y+z-pv))/q)$$

Assume that $q=b+gc$ and $w=r+gd$ for any integer $g$

Thus, we get $$x=((-dg+(pv-t-y-z-r))/(b+cg))$$

However, it is possible to choose $g$ such that $x$ is not a positive integer or it is a rational number.

Then where is the error in this proof.

Comment: 'It is possible to choose $g$ such that $x$ is not a positive integer". It is not correct statement for your set-up.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: No, the expressions of $q$ and $w$ are given for any  $g$

Comment: Yes, for any $g$ we can represent $q$ and $w$ as $q=b+gc$ and $w=r+gd$ with some $b$, $c$, $d$ and $r$. But how did you prove that there is some $g$ such that $x$ is not a positive integer? Consider the following problem: $x=a/b$, where $x$, $a$, $b$ are positive integers. Take $a=3$, $b=2$. Then $x=3/2$ which is not positive integer. Where is error? The error is that we cannot take arbitrary values for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your $g$-part does not touches $t$,$y$,$z$,$pv$ we can mark $pv-t-y-z=a$. Then we know that positive integer $x$ satisfies equation $x=\frac{a-w}{q}$, where $a$, $w$, $q$ are also positive integers. Then $a-w\equiv 0 \pmod q$, then exists integer $n$ such that $a-w=nq$. As $x$ and $q$ are both positive so $a-w>0$, then $n$ is positive integer. $a-w=nq\Rightarrow a=w+nq$. Let take $q=b+gc$, $w=r+gd$, then $a=w+nq=(r+gd)+n(b+gc)=g(d+nc)+r+nb$. Then $x=\frac{g(d+nc)+r+nb-w}{q}=$ $\frac{g(d+nc)+r+nb-r-gd}{b+gc}=\frac{nb+gnc}{b+gc}=n$ for any $g$.